# Programmatically set the Titles/Values collection of a Multi Value Setting (Settings.bundle)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is it possible to define the set of options in a Multi Value setting in runtime?
The idea is to fill the set of options with the currently available options given from a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The settings bundle is part of your application bundle, and cannot be modified after the application has been installed.  When the Settings application is run, it accesses your application's settings bundle directly, your application is not run, so there is no opportunity for you to provide different information.  Dynamic settings must be implemented as part of your application.

Comment: I suspected that was the case and it makes sense. I confess i was hoping more for some hack that would allow me to write the settings to the file but its just not worth it for my case. Thanks.